# Excel Get all fields in column into same date format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column in Excel with an issue that some fields have a strange format exported.

The overall format should be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Currently in the table

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-09-13 16:59:11 |
| 2022-11-16 06:39:40.027 |

Once I remove the .### at the end of the wrong fields manually they jump into the correct format.

As the dataset is large, I need a quick way to remove the .### from all fields where it occurs.

Any help is much appreciated

Manually removing the .### works but the dataset is too large for it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be specific about the way you are considering to achieve the result? Search-and-replace? Formulas? VBA? Edit SQL of the data query? (would be the best solution for me.)

Comment: Test if the value is text, if so find the `.` and return everything to the left of that.

Comment: Select column, open Find and replace menu with CTRL+F, choose replace tab. In find what field enter .* , leave replace with field empty, press replace all.

Comment: @user11222393 that will remove all the time parts of the items if they are true date/time. As true date/time is stored as a double and if their decimal separator is `.` it will remove the decimal which is the time.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is for the numbers to have a consistent format, rather than a technical need to round the seconds down to integer seconds.  If the data is already recognized as numeric date values by Excel, then just select the whole column and apply the “yyyy-mm-did hh:mm:ss” format to the entire column.  If they are stored as text then use `=VALUE(A2)` to convert them into an Excel date value and then paste-as-value the whole column over the existing data.  If you want them to end up text instead of Excel dates, then `=TEXT(VALUE(A2),”yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss”)` would do that.